# How do I write or read Google-Sheets "comments" on mobile devices?

Tags: google-sheets, android, iphone

In a Google-Sheet called **Field Schedules** for Google web-apps at http://drive.google.com you can right click on a cell to open a context menu with the option to "Insert comment." Let's say for example I insert a comment: **"hello world."** into the cell "**A1**."

After I create comments, I attempt to open the same Google-Sheet, **Field Schedules** on my Boss's iPad, or on my LG-G2-Android device and I do not see any option to "Insert comment[s]." Nor can I find comments that already exist.

After exiting the **Field Schedules** from the Android & Apple devices I can confirm that the original comment exists by using my desktop computer to open **Field Schedules** and hovering my cursor over "**A1**" it will then display my comment "**hello world.**"

#### TLDR: How do I write or read Google-Sheets "comments" on mobile devices?

Comment: That would be on-topic for the Android Enthusiasts: http://android.stackexchange.com/. Just tried it and was able to reproduce your findings. I guess the mobile app isn't ready yet to cope with the comments. The list view, as an option in the mobile app, isn't showing the comments either.

Comment: @Xzila: Are you using the Google Drive app or just the browser?

Comment: @AlE. I was using the official Google Drive app from the Google play store. I was able to see comments with the official Google Chrome browser after "Request[ing] desktop site." The problem with using the browser on desktop-mode for google drive is that it is reaaaaly buggy.

My interaction with the spreadsheet is via the web-app ( on a desktop computer ) to my Boss's iPad. It would be nice to not have to create a new column just for commenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer would appear to be: You can't. (At least right now.)

[From Google Support, regarding the Android app](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2440299):

> The Drive app doesn’t currently support viewing and editing comments in Google spreadsheets or Google presentations.

[Google Support, iOS app](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2498081):

> The Drive app doesn’t currently support viewing and editing comments in Google spreadsheets or Google presentations.

[Collaborate on documents in a mobile browser](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/1066277) doesn't mention comments at all. However, from my experimenting, it doesn't look like comments are available there either. (Which makes sense; the mobile browser version is a limited subset of functionality.)

Comment: That answers my question. I attempted to use the Chrome-mobile browser. In the spreadsheets default view the first column with the header **Row** has the word **edit** for every row. This view does not allow you to view comments. If you go to settings in the browser and select "Request desktop site," you will return to the same page with an additional option at the top "Go to spreadhseet view." If you click on "Go to spreadhseet view," you are now capable of seeing comments but this mode is **really buggy**.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this now!

1. Select the cell you want to add a note to. Tap in the blue area and select *Note* from the menu that appears.
2. A text entry screen will appear. Type in your note and tap **OK**.
3. Cells with attached notes will have a small black tick in the upper right corner. Select the cell and go to Note like you did in step one to view and edit an exiting note.

Comment: I can confirm this for Android -- but I don't see this working on iOS yet.

Comment: Note is not the same as comment, they are different things. The question was about comments.